# How to style siblings that aren't being hovered?

Tags: html, css

There's an effect I want to achieve where when a list item is hovered, all other list items are faded out.

I'm looking for a way of applying a style to an element which is not being hovered, when one of it's siblings are hovered.

I've come close with two approaches:

**1. Detecting hover on parent**

The problem with this is that hovering anywhere in the parent element, even between the anchor tags causes the effect. This isn't desirable, it should only apply the effect when hovering over the actual list item.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.d-flex:hover a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.d-flex:hover a {
  color: white;
}

.d-flex a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 1</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 2</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 3</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 4</a></div>
</div>
```

**2. Using the ~ operator**

This is close but the problem here is that the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) only selects siblings which appear *after* the element in the DOM.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

.item:hover ~ .item a{
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 1</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 2</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 3</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 4</a></div>
</div>
```

> **PLEASE NOTE:** I'm looking for a CSS only solution to this problem. I know it can be achieved with JavaScript, however I'm trying to avoid
>   that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good with your first method. Simply consider `pointer-events` to disable the hover on the empty spaces and keep it only on the links:

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.d-flex:hover a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.d-flex:hover a {
  color: white;
}

.d-flex a {
  color: blue;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 1</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 2</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 3</a></div>
  <div class="item"><a href="#">item 4</a></div>
</div>
```